# Overloading conversion operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

when a operator function is implemented as a member function left most operand must be object of operator's class
but in code below

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class ffloat {
      private:
        float a;
      public:
        ffloat():a(34.566){}
        operator int () {
          return a=static_cast<int >(a);
        }
     };

     int main() {
       ffloat w;
       int x;
       x=w;
       cout<<x<<endl;
     }
```

left most operand is variable,then why compiler didn't send a error
Thanks in advance....

Comment: `return a=static_cast<int >(a);` Do you understand what this does? If you made your operator a const function, the compiler would prevent this probable mistake.

Comment: is something wrong with that...

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking if you understand what it does. It will change the value of `a` in the object.

Comment: yess... But i wrote code keeping operator overloading in mind....@neil krirk

Comment: @virusai the normal semantics of conversion operator is that it returns a converted value but without making any change to the object. For example `ffloat w; cout << static_cast<int>(w); cout << "," << w << endl;` ought to display `34 34.566` but in your code it will display `34 34`.

Comment: understood... i believe it must be return  static_cast<int >(a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator int()` is a conversion function and its only operand is the implicit 'this' argument. Therefore `x=w` is not violating the rule since x is not an operand to the conversion. This is in part why it is fine to write `int(w)` there is no missing operand here. The rule you are referring to is about operators like '+ - * /' which can have 2 operands.

Comment: Then conversion operator behaves as unary operator ' correct me if am wrong '

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `a=static_cast<int >(a)` means that `a` should be casted as integer from float `a` and then it returns that as an integer.

Everything is valid, your operator `int` should return `int`

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: let `a` to be the integer version of former value of `a` (it will be rounded)
and then return this as the return value as well

Comment: This `operator int` will modify the state of the object. This is not how conversion operations usually work.

Comment: Well, it's not forbidden to alter the state (it's not a "const" :) )

Comment: That's not what am asking what am i asking is according to rule " when a operator function is implemented as a member function left most operand must be object of operator's class
"but in code above object is not left most operand....

Comment: "Where did this rule come fromm" try compiling this u will learn that rule. #include<iostream> using namespace std; class ffloat { private: float a; public: ffloat():a(34.566){} float operator +(float c) { return c+a; } }; int main() { ffloat w; float x; float s= x+w; cout<<s; }@neil krik

Comment: @virusai the variable x is not an operand to `operator int()` it is an operand to the assignment that is performed after.

Comment: Please try provide to detailed explanation am not getting u completely @rpattiso

Comment: @virusai i think you miss the point between casting "operator" [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) and other operators, which does need the leftmost parameter, you mentioned

This example you commented should comple if you make operator float() instead of operator +